# Xamarin: Get MvxRecyclerView working

Tags: c#, android, android-recyclerview, mvvmcross

I am working with Xamarin and **MvvmCross** to build a nice Android App. And I am trying to get the `MvxRecyclerView` working but I cannot get it right. The app **runs but doesn't show anything** in the `RecycleView`.

This is the view I have created (MainView.axml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvItems"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/itemview"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource TestItems" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The ViewModel I created (MainViewModel.cs):

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<TestModel> TestItems { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        TestItems = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>
        {
            new TestModel()
            {
                Name = "Test1"
            },
            new TestModel()
            {
                Name = "Test2"
            }
        };
    }

    public override Task Initialize()
    {
        //TODO: Add starting logic here

        return base.Initialize();
    }
}
```

The itemview (ItemView.cs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://scehmas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name" />
```

**As you can see in the example it is a simple, but I cannot get it to work.**

[Github link](https://github.com/kevingoos/RecycleViewTest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate issues here:

1. The width of your `ItemTemplate` is `0dp`, so it's not rendering. Change it to `match_parent`. I see you're trying to use `layout_weight` instead, but for that to work the parent `LinearLayout` needs a `weightSum`.
2. Your `TextView` is not bound to the value of `Name` from your model. Add `local:MvxBind="Text Name"` to the `TextView`.

Make those two changes and you should see your `RecyclerView` the way you expect:

[image]

Comment: It works. One small question still: Why do I need android:text="Name" and local:MvxBind="Text Name". Because when I leave out the android:text property it stopts working.

Comment: I couldn't say without taking another look, but it should work without `android:text`. Very strange.

Comment: @LukePorthier I updated the github, if you have some time somewhere, you can maybe take a look :)